# Add html to an html file that was previously loaded with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have loaded an html file using the `jQuery` `.load` function into another html file. The loaded html file has a div of id **random_div**. Is it possible, for example, the html `<div id="loaded_html_div"></div>` into the `#random_div`?

Here is what I've come up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // random.html has the div of id random_div
    $('#html_container').load('random.html');

    $('#random_div').html('<div id="loaded_html_div"></div>');
)};
```

I've also tried

```
$('#random_div').append('<div id="loaded_html_div"></div>');
$('#random_div').load('<div id="loaded_html_div"></div>');
```

They don't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: `Basically, does this work` - odd question to ask if you already know it doesn't

Comment: @JaromandaX True... I must be tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append div after another file successfully loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#html_container').load('random.html', function(){
        // Whatever you want to add in #random_div.
        $('#random_div').html('<div id="loaded_html_div"></div>');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add HTML before the element is loaded since ajax is an asynchronous process. So do it within the success callback of [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#html_container').load('random.html'function(){
        $('#random_div').html('<div id="loaded_html_div"></div>');
    });    
});
```